Any support for cuTENSORMg in python?
I have recently been looking into cuTENSOR (+cupy) for a speedy tensor contraction GPU library, and have been wanting to extend my single GPU code to multi GPU distributed code via cuTENSORMg;
however, I have not been able to find any pythonic support (especially through things like cupy) for cuTENSORMg, and upon doing something like
import cupyx

print(dir(cupyx))

I have only been able to find cupyx.cutensor (single GPU presumably), and no functions to indicate multi-GPU support. I was wondering whether anyone has any tips regarding this, or whether anyone can point to some examples using cuTENSORMg in python.

cuTENSORMg support is in the CuPy's main branch. There's no release including the support yet, so you will need to build it from source by your own for now.

Thanks for letting me know! And if I understand correctly, cuTENSORMg is only single node multi GPU, so if I owuld have a multi node application, I would be better off using mpi4py (or similar) + cuTENSOR rather than cuTENSORMg , right?
